# Can i use this.props.navigation.state.params in export function?

Tags: react-native

I need to get `this.props.navigation.state.params`

I got error

> cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

How its posible please help

```
export default function PlaySong() {  
  useEffect(() => {
    EventRegister.addEventListener('playSong', (data) => {
      console.log('playSong - '+data)  
    })  
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this sample:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

function PlaySong() {  
  useEffect(() => {
    EventRegister.addEventListener('playSong', (data) => {
      console.log('playSong - '+data)  
    })  
  }); 
} 

export default withNavigation(PlaySong);
```

Or you can send `this.props.navigation` to your component as a `prop` and use it.

Comment: You should also tell the OP how he can get `this.props.navigation.state.params` in this component.